# test class - not working

Tags: trigger, unit-test, opportunity

I have written a Trigger as following

```
trigger OppIDtoLookup on ONB2__Invoice__c (before insert, before update) {
    for (ONB2__Invoice__c a : trigger.new){
        if(a.OppID__c != null){
            a.Opportunity__c = a.OppID__c ;
        } 
    } 
}
```

and I wrote a Test Class as following:

```
@IsTest
public class TESTONB2Invoice {
    static testMethod void TESTONB2Invoice_trigger()
    {
        Account a = new Account(Name = 'testAccount',
                                BillingPostalCode = '83059',
                                BillingCountry = 'Deutschland',
                                Genaue_Anzahl_Mitarbeiter__c = 3,
                                Anzahl_Mitarbeiter__c = '0-5',
                                z_Region_WV__c = 'Hamburg');
        insert a; 

        ONB2__Template__c  b = new ONB2__Template__c (Name = 'testTemplate');
        insert b;

    ONB2__InvoiceCounter__c  c = new ONB2__InvoiceCounter__c (Name = 'Default');
        insert c;

        Pricebook2 d = new Pricebook2 (Name = 'Standard');
        insert d;

        Product2 e =new Product2 (Name = 'Top AG');
        insert e;

        Pricebookentry f = new Pricebookentry (Pricebook2Id = '01sD0000000hbEh',
                                               Product2Id = e.Id,
                                               UnitPrice = 250,
                                               usestandardprice = false,
                                               isactive = true);
        insert f;

        Opportunity g = new Opportunity (Name = 'testOpp',
                                         Account = a,
                                         Amount = 250,
                                         Override_Region__c = 'Hamburg',
                                         Pricebook2 = d,
                                         StageName = '40 - Demo Termin vereinbart',
                                         CloseDate = date.today(),
                                         z_Vertragsbeginn__c = date.today());
        insert g;

        OpportunityLineItem h = new OpportunityLineItem (OpportunityId = g.Id,
                                                         Quantity = 1,
                                                         TotalPrice = 250,
                                                         PricebookentryId = f.Id);
        insert h;

        ONB2__Invoice__c invoice = new ONB2__Invoice__c(ONB2__Account__c = a.id, 
                                                        ONB2__Template__c = b.id, 
                                                        ONB2__Status__c = 'Draft', 
                                                        OppID__c = g.Id); 
        insert invoice;

        invoice = [SELECT OppId__c, Opportunity__c FROM ONB2__Invoice__c WHERE Id = :invoice.Id];
        System.AssertEquals(invoice.Opportunity__c, invoice.OppId__c);
    }
}
```

unfortunately, there is another Testclass as following, which returns the error below, what can i do to pass both test classes

```
* Description.: Called from Trigger for automatic Pricebook assignment
* Objects.....: Opportunity, Account, Pricebook, PricebookEntry
* =================================================================
*/
public without sharing class Opportunity_TriggerHelper {

  public static void beforeAction(List<Opportunity> triggerlist, Map<Id,Id> OppAccMap) {
    Map<Id,Account> AccMap = new Map<Id,Account>();
    for (Account a : [Select Id, Anzahl_Mitarbeiter__c, Region__c from Account where Id in :OppAccMap.values()]) {
      AccMap.put(a.Id, a);
    }
    Map<String,Id> PricebookMap = new Map<String,Id>();
    for (Pricebook2 pb : [Select Id, Name, IsStandard from Pricebook2 where isActive = true]) {
      PricebookMap.put((pb.IsStandard ? 'Standard' : pb.Name), pb.Id);
    }
    Map<String,Decimal> PriceMap = new Map<String,Decimal>();
    for (PricebookEntry pbe : [Select Id, Name, UnitPrice, isActive, Pricebook2Id from PricebookEntry where isActive = true and (Name = 'Top AG' or Name like 'Premium Flat%')]) {
      PriceMap.put(mapKey(pbe.Pricebook2Id,empKey(pbe.Name,'PBE')),pbe.UnitPrice);
    }

    for (Opportunity o : triggerlist) {
      string pbKey = ( o.Override_Region__c != null && o.Override_Region__c != '' ) ? o.Override_Region__c : AccMap.get(o.AccountId).Region__c;
      if (o.Pricebook2Id == null)
        o.Pricebook2Id = PricebookMap.get(PricebookMap.keySet().contains(pbKey) ? pbKey : 'Standard');
      if (PriceMap.containsKey(mapKey(o.Pricebook2Id, empKey(AccMap.get(o.AccountId).Anzahl_Mitarbeiter__c,'ACC'))))
        o.Listenpreis_Premium_Flat__c = PriceMap.get(mapKey(o.Pricebook2Id, empKey(AccMap.get(o.AccountId).Anzahl_Mitarbeiter__c,'ACC')));
      if (PriceMap.containsKey(mapKey(o.Pricebook2Id, 'topag')))
        o.Listenpreis_Top_AG__c = PriceMap.get(mapKey(o.Pricebook2Id, 'topag'));
    }

  }
  private static string mapKey(Id pbId, string pbeName) { return pbId + '||' + pbeName ; }
  private static string empKey(string s, string source) {
    if (s == 'Top AG') return 'topag';
    if (source == 'PBE' && s != null && s != '') return string.valueOf(integer.valueOf(s.substring(13,16)));
    if (source == 'ACC' && s != null && s != '') return s.substring(0,s.indexOf((s.contains('-')) ? '-' : ' '));
    return null;
  }
}
```

Line 33 contains the following

```
if (PriceMap.containsKey(mapKey(o.Pricebook2Id, empKey(AccMap.get(o.AccountId).Anzahl_Mitarbeiter__c,'ACC'))))
```

here is the error message

```
caused by: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

Class.Opportunity_TriggerHelper.beforeAction: line 33, column 1
```

Comment: `Pricebook2Id = '01sD0000000hbEh'` dont use hardcoded id.  Also instead of `Pricebook2 = d` write `Pricebook2Id = d.Id`

Comment: Hi @Ratan thx for this, but i need to have the id of the standard pricebook, therefore i tried to use a select code, but this ended in 0 elements

Comment: In test class always use `test.getstandardpricebookid()` to get standard pricebookid.  can you just add your another test class

Comment: @Ratan but i need to have a test class including an Opportunity to cover the trigger,  i already tried to get the trigger developed with another testclass, but then it says, the trigger code is not covered, guess due to missing Opportunity

Comment: What does the calling code for `Opportunity_TriggerHelper.beforeAction()` look like?  I'm assuming `Map<Id,Id> OppAccMap` doesn't have the value you're after.  I also note you're assigning the Account to the Opportunity with `Account = a,`.  Shouldn't that be `Account = a.Id,`?